# Meaning of Quantum superposition, revisited

Tags: quantum-mechanics

While there were already [many](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/how-is-quantum-superposition-different-from-mixed-state) [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152982/165461) on superposition in quantum mechanics, with great answers, these somehow leaves me uncertain about its physical meaning once I think about it a bit further.

Let me explain why the explanation with the [double-slit experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/152989/165461) does not quite satisfy me. The system with the first (respectively, the second) slit open can be described by a Schroedinger equation of the form 
$$
ih\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = (-\Delta + V_{1,2})\Psi,
$$
where the potential $V_{1}$ (resp. $V_2$) is, say, large negative at the first slit (resp., the second one) and zero elsewhere at the wall.  If both slits are open, the equation can be written as

$$
ih\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = (-\Delta + V_{1}+V_2)\Psi.
$$
If $\Psi_{1,2}$ are solutions to the former equation, then $\Psi_1+\Psi_2$ is approximately a solution to latter one. Note that we are actually adding states corresponding to *two different* physical systems, to obtain a state of a *third* system.

The same applies to the [reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/152991/165461) example. We are using two different solutions to the free particle Schroedinger equation to cook up a solution to the equation with a barrier.

So far it all looks like merely a mathematical trick, exploiting nice features of the Schroedinger equation. We are not adding two states of the same physical system. So, the question is:

- What is a physical meaning of adding *two states of the same system*?

One thing that concerns me here is the following. As far as I understand, the state space of a quantum-mechanical system is not, actually, a Hilbert space, but a complex projective space over a Hilbert space: the wave function should be normalized, and multiplication by $e^{i\alpha}$ leads to a physically indistinguishable state. Now, if quantum superposition had a physical meaning, then adding two states should be well-defined over this projective space, which it is not. In other words,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\psi_1\rangle+e^{i\alpha}|\psi_2\rangle)
$$
corresponds to physically different states for different choice of $\alpha$, while $e^{i\alpha}|\psi_2\rangle$ describes the same state.

Comment: if you take your state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\psi_1\rangle+e^{i\alpha}|\psi_2\rangle)$ and multiply it by $e^{i\alpha}$ you DO get a physically indistinguishable state.  Multiplication of a single factor like $\vert\psi_2\vert$ by a phase is not the same as multiplication of a full state by a phase.

Comment: I think that @ZeroTheHero might have read your final paragraph too hastily and missed the point.   You are right that even when $B$ and $B'$ represent the same state, $\gamma(A+B)$ and $\gamma(A+B')$  can represent **different** states, and, contrary to the apparent meaning of the above comment, no multiplication by a scalar can change that.

Comment: @WillO I removed my answer as I would rather not mislead the OP.  I will re-read the qustion again.  I agree $\gamma(A+B')$ will be different from $\gamma(A+B)$ and I thought this is exactly what my comment expressed...

Comment: @zerothehero:  it's of course possible that your answer was fine and I misread it; I can't doublecheck now that you've deleted.   The content of the answer was certainly fine, but I did think it was answering a different question than the one that was asked.

Comment: @WillO No worries.  I'll double check later today.