# According to the Copenhagen Interpretation what does superposition mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

I am not interested in Many Worlds Interpretation because I think it’s mental and after some personal research I found out that it wasn’t (despite some claims otherwise) popular among physicists  at all.  But in the orthodox interpretation, what does being in a superposition mean. Does it mean it isn’t in any position yet before it is measured and has several possibilities. Or is it actually in multiple states/places at once. In the talk of Serge Haroche it seems like the latter https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=RM7_we-F7hQ also the way David Wineland’s research is being described here www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/popular-physicsprize2012.pdf seems to say it’s in multible states at once. But I’ve also seen it described (for instance by David Mermin) as being nowhere untill measured. Which one is it?

Comment: Long story short : you can interpret whichever way you want, more or less. We can't know something that is not an observable, and by definition we will not observe something to be in multiple states at once. There is no right answer as what happens before the measurement, just interpretations of the framework that is used, namely in this case quantum mechanics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The meaning of Superposition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152982/)