# Superposition of Quantity

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra, superposition, linear-systems

I searched the first page of search result "Superposition" the closest answer came was [The Meaning of Superposition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152982/) but what noted that major answers are in context of Quantum Mechanics.
My question is intuitive nature of superposition" term. Superposition seems to be vector addition. as in electric fields the superposition at certain point is addition of all vectors at that point. Superposition is interference (SUM) of all the individual parameters

1 - Does this means that all "QUANTITIES" with vector attributes have superposition?

2 - Does any vector quantity do not have superposition

3 - Are there scalar quantity with superposition

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Zaellix kindly point me how to make Q more specific. In my case the nature of problem is not specific as the term is encountered in diverse fields but the underlying mathematical interpretation of term as an operator; as described in the answer remains the same. On a side note are the ans here verified. sorry just a newbie.

Comment: @gandalf61 kindly confirm me if my interpretation of answer is correct - in simplest way superposition is mathematical operator just as addition.

Comment: @gandalf61 Regarding scalar quantity i am not convinced since scalars are usually 1 dimensional so can undergo simple arithmetic operations. that's why i added 3 part of question - Is there any specific superposition instance where superposition is used as scalar quantities analysis.

Comment: You overthink. Mathematically superposition is just a linear combination, but physical meaning of  superpositions in classical and quantum physics is very different.

Comment: Mathematically, any system response function which obeys [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) must satisfy additivity and homogeneity (system response to a scaled stimulus must be the same as scaled response to a unitary stimulus). Btw, the stimuli and responses could be numbers, functions, vectors, vector fields, time-varying signals. So linear map is not limited to vectors only.

Comment: @Sage, my intention was to encourage you to focus on one of the three questions you have placed. It's good practice to "divide-and-conquer" your problems and in that sense it could be good to ask different questions and reference each other. Since people are able to help you though it's absolutely fine. My comment was more of a recommendation than an "instruction". Maybe it was not too clear and I apologise for that.

Answer (score 6):

In physics in general (not just in quantum physics), the term "superposition" just means "linear combination". Any vector quantity can be thought of as the superposition of basis vectors. For example, if we travel $\sqrt 2$ miles north-east, this can be thought of as the superposition of travelling $1$ mile north and $1$ mile east. A scalar quantity can be though of as a superposition too - for example, the complex number $1+i$ can be thought of as the superposition of $1$ and $i$ (whether or not this is a useful point of view depends on the context).

The unexpected thing in quantum physics is that the state of a system behaves like a vector quantity. In classical physics a system is either in a given state or it is not - a switch is either on or off; a particle is either at this location or it is somewhere else. But in quantum physics the state of a system is a linear combination  of basis states (and, to add a further twist, the multipliers of the basis states are complex numbers rather than real numbers).

So whereas a classical switch can only be off $|0\rangle$ or on $|1\rangle$, a quantum switch (also known as a [qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) in quantum computing) has a state

$\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers (and, conventionally, they are scaled so that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$). This combination of classical states is a superposition.

Answer (score 0):

Superposition generally involves orthogonal vectors as stationnary states are orthogonal. Superposition of scalar quantities is not interesting as they do not always fulfill orthogonality. Any vector in 3D is a superposition of orthogonal vectors but you might not guess an unique orthogonal basis generating the corresponding vector.